# Show that $v_i^2 > v_i v_{i+1}$ where $\vec{v} \in R^m$

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

I am trying to show that the matrix
$$
B_h = 
\left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
2 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & \ddots & \ddots \\
0 & 0 & \ddots & \ddots \\
\end{array} \right]
$$
is positive definite. I am using the definition for positive definite 
$$
\vec{v}^{\,T} B_h \vec{v} > 0
$$
I have multiplied the vectors out, collected the terms, and have gotten the sum below.
$$
2 \left( \sum \limits_{n = 1}^{N-1} v_n^2 - \sum \limits_{n = 1}^{N-2} v_n v_{n+1} \right)
$$
where $\vec{v} \in R^m$. The problem is I have no idea how to show that $v_n^2 > v_n v_{n+1}$, which I am assuming is the way to show that the sums are greater than 0. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sum is equal to
$$v_1^2 + \sum_{i = 1}^{n-1}(v_i - v_{i + 1})^2 + v_n^2$$
and hence is positive.

Comment: I see what you did there. Thanks!